# Hibernate refresh session with deleted object in DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an object **Sample** that contains a *Collection* of **Foo** objects.

```
public class Sample {

  private String name;
  private List<Foo> fooList;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String n) {
    name = n;
  }

  public List<Foo> getFooList() {
    return fooList;
  }

  public void setFooList(List<Foo> list) {
    fooList = list;
  }

}
```

The objects Sample and Foo are correctly mapped in Hibernate.

I open ah Hibernate transaction and I have in a cache an instance of Sample with "name" = "tommaso".
Someone modifiy in the DB that row and change name in "massimo".
If I want to refresh the instance in cache, I write

```
Sample sample = ...;
session.refresh(sample);
```

Hibernate refresh the instance of Sample object and the attribute *name* became "massimo". It works!

If someone edit the collection of this instance, and delete one *Foo* in the *fooList*, when I do refresh of that instance *Sample*, Hibernate throws **no row with the given identifier exists**.

How can I refresh the session cache with real situation in the db?

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the `UnresolvableObjectException` and `evict` the sample from the cache yourself:

```
public boolean refreshOrEvict(Session session, Object entity) {
    try {
        session.refresh(entity);
        return true;
    } catch (UnresolvableObjectException e) {
        session.evict(entity);
        return false;
    }
}
```